# Change permissions of directory

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chmod

I have a directory with **drwxrwxr-x+** permissions. I want to change this permission to **drwxr-xr-x**

Please suggest the command to change the above permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze the desired result:

`drwxr-xr-x`

`d` just means this is a directory, we can ignore it:

`rwxr-xr-x`

translate it to binary code:

`11110101` (0 is equivalent to `-`).

Translate each 3 digits to a decimal number:

`755`: 111 → 7, 101 → 5

Eventually just type this:

`chmod 755 <dirname>`

Comment: just a doubt...if I do 777 inplace of 755....will that also work?

Comment: No @Mahesh, that will give drwxrwxrwx permission, as 7 is equivalent to rwx and 5 to r_x.

Comment: @Mahesh if you use 755, 'group' and 'world' are not granted with writing permissions, but only with execution and reading. If you use 777 instead, they will have writing permissions as well.

Comment: @noam I have just did 755 command, and now my directory permissions are **drwxr-xr-x+** ... There is an extra **+** at the end? is this normal? how to change that to x?

Comment: The command given by Noam is correct, just to clarify your doubt, I mentioned that 7 represent sets of (1, 1, 1) for (r, w, x) and 5 represents (1, 0, 1) as 0 means we don't want that permission, so 5 will result in only r_x permission with w missing. You can check the alternative way to change permissions, I have answered below. That method makes more literal sense.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
chmod g-w <dirName>
```

'chmod' command can be used to change permissions for 'user', 'group', and 'others'. You can use the shorthand notation "u/g/o" in combination or individually, along with "+/-" and "r/w/x" to control the permissions.

Permissions look like this "drwxrwxrwx":

- u - user's permissions (Represtend by first three characters after d
  in permissions)

  g - group's permissions(Represtend by next three characters
  after user's permissions)

  o - others permissions (Represtend by next three characters
  after group's permissions)
- '+/-' : Choose either to remove or add permission
- 'r/w/x' : Types of permisson r-read, w-write, x-execute

Comment: The directory permission is now **drwxr-xr-x+** ... however, there is a trailing + , removing that will cause any issues?

Comment: Reading the extra '+' in end, I think that is for some additional ACLs set, not sense generally. Read this for more details https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92071

Comment: I think it should not bother you, you can leave it.